# How to know each string length by words in C++

Tags: c++-cli

want to know how split each string and get, number of words. But I keep getting a error 'Split': is not a member of 'System::Array' with a split or piece in a third line.

```
String^ originalString = textBox1->Text;//original text string
cli::array<String^>^ piece= originalString->Split('.');//text is being split into sentences    
cli::array<String^>^ sentence = piece->Split(' ');// text is being split into words, also I get error here
for (int i = 0; i < sentence->Length; ++i) {
datagridview1->Rows[i]->Cells[2]->Value = i;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest thing you can do is to use `Regex`:

```
String^ text = "This is a chord. This is another. This is a third. Now form a band.";

int wordCount = Regex::Matches(text, "\\w+")->Count; // = 15
```

where

> `\w` stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

[Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

---

Update to:

> but I need a number of words in each sentence

under this circumstances this should work for you:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::Linq;
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;

static int CountWords(String^ text) 
{
    return Regex::Matches(text, "\\w+")->Count;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ text = "This is a chord. This is another. This is a third. Now form a band.";

    // split sentences
    IEnumerable<String^>^ sentences = Regex::Split(text, "[.!?](?!$)"); 
    List<int>^ wordCounts = Enumerable::ToList(
        // count words for each sentence
        Enumerable::Select<String^, int>(sentences, gcnew Func<String^, int>(&CountWords)));
}
```

where:

- `[.!?]` matches any of those three sentence endings and thus splits the text there
- `(?!$)` it's a negative lookahead `?!`, it makes sure the last sentence ending `.!?` is not at the end of text `$` which would result in an empty string

Comment: This is very nice example, but I need a number of words in each sentence. So according your String^ text I should get answer 4; 3; 4; 4.

Comment: This information is not included in your question that is by the way not very clear so I couldn't have known it ;-]

Comment: @DeividasKiznis I updated my answer. You can check if the new solution satisfies your requirements ;-)

Comment: Code looks fine and everything, but when copied code, I get bunch of errors: like a my namespace doesn't recognise a Linq and few others words in code like IEnumerable or Regex (even when I include library). I don't know is that important but but my file has extension h not cpp. By the way I'm really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's hard to say why it doesn't work in your project. If you like I've uploaded my test project to github, you can find it here: https://github.com/he-dev/Q33202877 it's been created with VS20015 Community ;-) c++/cli is sometimes strange I had also a small problem with linq, I've added a reference to System.Core and it probably fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can begin by getting *sentences*, which are groups of words separated by a "." character, then get the *words* for each sentence, which are separated by a blank character.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

String^ originalString = "This is a chord. This is another. This is a third. Now form a band.";

// This array contains the sentences, which are separated by '.'
array<String^>^ sentences = originalString->Split(
    gcnew array<String^> { "." },
    StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries);

Debug::Assert(sentences->Length == 4);

// This list contains individual words for all sentences.
List<String^>^ words = gcnew List<String^>();
for each(String^ sentence in sentences) {
    words->AddRange(sentence->Split(
        gcnew array<String^> { " " },
        StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries));
}

Debug::Assert(words->Count == 15);

for each(String^ word in words) {
    Console::WriteLine(word);
}
```

But if the only thing you are interested in are the individual *words*, you can get them in a single expression using LINQ:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::Linq;

System::String^ StripDot(System::String^ input) {
    return input->Replace(".", "");
}

void Test()
{
    String^ originalString = "This is a chord. This is another. This is a third. Now form a band.";

    IEnumerable<String^>^ words = Enumerable::Select<String^,String^>(
        originalString->Split(
            gcnew array<String^> { " " },
            StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries),
        gcnew Func<String^,String^>(StripDot));

    Debug::Assert(Enumerable::Count(words) == 15);

    for each(String^ word in words) {
        Console::WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I bet it's correct, but could you give more simple variant, because when I try to used I get few errors. Thank you nevertheless.